# Given a formula $2|x|+3|y|\leq 12$, how many integer pairs of (x, y) are there?

Tags: inequality, contest-math, absolute-value

I just had a seventh grade math Olympiad test, and I had this question that confused me.

> Given a formula $2|x|+3|y|\leq 12$, how many integer pairs of (x, y) are there?

I just checked in Desmos, and the answer was 15.

In the test, I didn't really have much time to ponder this. I don't know why I did this, but somehow I managed to just remove the absolute value signs and wrote this:
$$\begin{align}&2|x|+3|y|\leq 12\\
\Rightarrow &2x+3y\leq 12\end{align}$$

I really don't know how I did that. But what I know is that I did it wrong during the test. So how DO I do this question?

Comment: Hint: $2|x|\leq 2|x|+3|y| \leq 12$ so $|x| \leq 6$. Similarly, $|y| \leq 4$. But not all choices of $|x| \leq 6$ and  $|y| \leq 4$ give the original inequality.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy Ah. So does this mean that I just need to go through each of the x and y pairs and check if they satisfy the inequality? Or is there a faster way to go through each of the pairs to see if they are valid?

Comment: Yes. Note that if $x=\pm 6$ then we get $3|y| \leq 0$ so $y$ must be $0$. It is not hard to list all possible pairs $(x,y)$.

Comment: One minute from when modulus or |x| started in class 7? As far as I remember modulus or |x| is taught in class 11. Also tackling inequalities are taught in class 11. In class 7 we are just taught to tackle equalities

Comment: There are $53$ pairs and not $15$. I would not try anything fancy in 3-4 minutes, rather I would just count them using symmetry.

Answer (score 1):

$F:2|x|+3|y|\leq 12$ is the figure formed by the four lines $\pm 2x\pm 3y=12$. Count the number of integer points on these four lines. The number of points inside $F$ will then be anyways easy to count.

Looking at the graph of $2|x|+3|y|\leq 12$ (or in general $m|x|+n|y|\leq r$) may help.

Comment: I'm supposed to do this in 4-5 minutes, without any graph paper, a calculator, or a graphing calculator, because this is a test. I don't think drawing the graph would help.

Comment: @Tyrcnex I just asked you to have a look at the graph, noe that you are in the comfort of your home. Actually, this graph is a very standard curve and it's useful to keep the figure in mind (or at least be able to construct it quickly). That's why I asked you to look at the general curve of $m|x|+n|y|\leq r$

Comment: I looked at the graph in Desmos. How is this a curve? It's more of a quadrilateral (4 lines)

Comment: @Tyrcnex It's actually a rhombus, and the four triangles are equivalent. Note (algebraically and geometrically) where the lines intersect.

Comment: Well, thank you for the answer! I now understand this question more. +1

Comment: @Tyrcnex You are welcome!